# How to exclude results within the Mongo aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to the Mongo aggregation pipeline, and what I'm trying to do is find a simple way to exclude documents from my query. Each document in this collection can have multiple `usernames`. What I'm trying to exclude in my aggregation are any documents which have usernames other than `userA` and `userB`. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
...
{$dontmatch: {usernames: {$nin: ['userA', 'userB']}}}
```

My current query:

```
...
{$match:{
    $or: [
        {$and: [{usernames: {$size: 1}}, {usernames: {$in: ["userA", "userB"]}}]},
        {$and: [{usernames: {$size: 2}}, {usernames: {$all: ["userA", "userB"]}}]}
    ]}
}
```

What I have at the moment works, but I'm just wondering if there is a more clean or efficient way of doing this, such as I've suggested above?

Comment: So `[ [ "A", "B" ],  [ "A", "C" ], [ "A" ], [ "B" ], [ "B", "C" ] ]` would reduce down to `[ [ "A", "B" ], [ "A" ], [ "B" ] ]` on a selection of `[ "A", "B" ]`? BTW these are query conditions, and since it can be done in a query condition then the aggregation framework should have nothing to do with it. You can use operators to calculate most things, but a matching "query" is always the fastest method.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The input to this stage is the result of a previous $group and part of a much larger query, that's why I'm using the aggregation framework.

Comment: Then use `$match`. That is basically a "query". Maybe try editing your question to explain what you are doing a little better if that is not what you want. It's sat around for a couple of weeks, which strongly suggests your intent is unclear.

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is if there is a way to have the oppoosite of a `$match`, where I can specify the results I want to filter out instead of results I want to keep. For example, if there was a third `"userC"` which I also wanted to include in my whitelist, the `$match` would get considerably more complicated for one new username, instead of just adding a value to an array as in my first theoretical example.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this, if I understand the question correctly - we want to exclude the documents where the usernames array contains anything other than "userA" and "userB".

One possible way to achieve this using aggregation pipeline would be something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oncv4_iRx35

Here's what I did:

1. Use $project stage to create empty "usernames" array where the condition doesn't satisfy
2. Use $addFields to add a size field containing the size of modified usernames array
3. Use $match to filter out the desired documents.

There might be more succinct approaches to this but this is the one I came up with.